# Converting System.Datetime? to System.DateTime in EntityFramework Mapped Class

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, datetime

I have a project in C# Visual Studio that uses EF to connect to a MySQL Database. The EF mapper has given me a class `"enteredtickets"` mapped from a MySQL view. My issue is that there is a property call `TicketDate` were the Data type is System.DateTime? as is MySQL and the date may be a null. The problem is I would like a System.DateTime.

So I would like to change the factory code of the EF mapped class to make the  finished property `TicketDate` a System.DateTime. However I am cautious of what to change in case I break the code!

From reading I am guessing I need a statement like

```
datetime??new DateTime(2000,1,1)
```

So my questions are

1. Should I be changing the Factory EF mapped code in the first place?
2. How should I build in the conversion to the EF mapped code?

The EF mapped factory code is

```
 public Nullable<global::System.DateTime> TicketDate
    {
        get
        {
            return _TicketDate;
        }
        set
        {
            OnTicketDateChanging(value);
            ReportPropertyChanging("TicketDate");
            _TicketDate = StructuralObject.SetValidValue(value);
            ReportPropertyChanged("TicketDate");
            OnTicketDateChanged();
        }
    }
    private Nullable<global::System.DateTime> _TicketDate;
    partial void OnTicketDateChanging(Nullable<global::System.DateTime> value);
    partial void OnTicketDateChanged();
```

The column property in the MySQL table the view is based on is

```
TABLE `ticket` CHANGE `created` `created` DATETIME NOT NULL;
```

***Additional information****
For further clarification the details of the MySQL view are

```
select `a`.`ticket_id` AS `ticket_id`,`a`.`status` AS `status`,`a`.`number` AS `number`,`b`.`subject` AS `subject`,`b`.`timespent` AS `timespent`,`a`.`staff_id` AS `staff_id`,`a`.`user_id` AS `user_id`,(case when isnull(`b`.`dayoffset`) then `a`.`created` else (`a`.`created` + interval ceiling(`b`.`dayoffset`) day) end) AS `TicketDate`,`b`.`sysdowntime` AS `sysdowntime`,`b`.`CliDowntime` AS `CliDowntime`,`b`.`TelDowntime` AS `TelDowntime`,`b`.`NetDowntime` AS `NetDowntime`,date_format((case when isnull(`b`.`dayoffset`) then `a`.`created` else (`a`.`created` + interval ceiling(`b`.`dayoffset`) day) end),'%Y%m%d') AS `groupingdate`,`b`.`priority_id` AS `priority_id` from (`ost`.`ost_ticket` `a` join `ost`.`ost_ticket__cdata` `b` on((`a`.`ticket_id` = `b`.`ticket_id`)))
```

However looking at the definition in MySQL the view is allowing Null for the `TicketDate`, not certain how to stop this

[image: MySQL View Definition]

Comment: The column in the table is `NOT NULL`, but is the view doing a join or something where it could end up being null?

Comment: That is something I did not think of. I thought my view was written to stop this. However looking at the definition in MySQL the view is allowing Null for the TicketDate, not certain how to stop this. I have add the the view code to the original question. Any ideas please?